# Console application for generating addresses and private keys

Tags: addresses, private-key, windows, console

Is there a Windows console application that can generate addresses and private keys as output to the console window?

Comment: I think a more appropriate solution on Windows would be using Nethereum. Check out their docs.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows platform you typically have the option to use [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum), a .NET web3 library. This is probably preferred as Windows comes with .NET runtime, so your user won't have to install node.js.

It's super simple to generate a private key and an account.

```
// using Nethereum.Signer;

var ecKey = EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKey();
var genAddress = ecKey.GetPublicAddress();

Console.WriteLine("Key is {0}", privateKey);
Console.WriteLine("Address is {0}", genAddress);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZ1X0l)

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript and nodejs.

Install nodejs and npm using the guide [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows).

Install the [keythereum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keythereum) npm package.

The keythereum docs (on that page) outline its usage.